# How do I temporarily seal a pet door?

Tags: doors, seal, pet-door

I would like to seal a pet door in my house to prevent curious toddlers at home from falling through it. I'd like the seal to look somewhat nice in appearance, and temporary so I can remove it if need be in the future. Any advice on how to go about doing this? See attached pictures of the two sides of the door for reference. The door opens to the garage and is made of strong material.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Pet doors often come with snap on, slide on or magnetic panels to close it.  Did you check the manufacturer's website for accessories or replacement closing panels?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm looking at the Petsafe website to see if I can find a closing panel.